# Using function in pgPointCloud extension to PostgreSQL with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, database

I am using the pgPointCloud extension to PostgreSQL and have created a table of blocks/patches of points in a point cloud. Now, I am just trying to run a few of the functions in the pgPointCloud/postgis extensions on the blocks, such as `PC_BoundingDiagonalGeometry(pcpatch)` and `PC_EnvelopeGeometry(pcpatch)`. However, both of these functions are failing with the same error message. For example, running

```
SELECT ST_AsText(PC_BoundingDiagonalGeometry(pa)) FROM patches;
```

returns

```
ERROR:  function pc_boundingdiagonalgeometry(pcpatch) does not exist  
LINE 1: SELECT ST_AsText(PC_BoundingDiagonalGeometry(pa)) FROM patch...  
                         ^ HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. 
You might need to add explicit type casts.   
SQL state: 42883  
Character: 18
```

I do not understand what is causing the problem. I have already created the POSTGIS, POINTCLOUD, and POINTCLOUD_POSTGIS extensions in my database.I have also created the patches table accordingly as described on this page:
https://github.com/pgpointcloud/pointcloud